# Can you var scope multiple variables at once in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

While it is possible and does not throw an error I would like to know if it's an approved practice to var scope multiple variables in one line like this:

```
<cfset VAR var1 = var2 = var3 = ''>
```

I would appreciate all ideas and opinions especially if they come with documentation as a supporting argument.  I know that it works without throwing an error but I can't find specific documentation saying whether it will scope a variable or if it just declares the value.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw: An easy way to test it is dump the function local scope: CF9/`#Local#` CF8/`#getPageContext().getActiveFunctionLocalScope()#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone said you need to scope your variables with `var` or `local`.  Also as @Ben said, you can't really var scope variables like you have.  What I would suggest is use the local scope and do something like the following:

```
<cfscript>
     var val = 'some value'
     local = {
          var1 = duplicate(val),
          var2 = duplicate(val),
          var3 = duplicate(val)
      };
</cfscript>
```

That, in my opinion, is the fastest way to achieve what you seem to be doing.  I use the duplicate function just so if you use a complex variable as the value of val (struct, array, etc) you don't run into issue with references.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, yes, you can do this in CF9:

```
<cfset var a = var b = c = d*5>
```

Here's [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS328B9130-F922-4ddb-B78B-8817CA81F8E3.html) which gives that example.  In this case I'm assuming variables `c` and `d` were already defined earlier in the function.

So you need to repeat the `var` keyword for each variable, and in your case this would result in:

```
<cfset VAR var1 = VAR var2 = VAR var3 = ''>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<cfset>` does not scope variables.

To properly scope the variables requires the `var` keyword

`<cfset var someVariable = 1>`

Otherwise the variables will be created, but assigned to the default scope.
The default scope depends on the context and what version of CF we are talking about.

For CFC methods:

- CF9 -> `LOCAL` scope
- CF8 -> `VARIABLES` scope

Because of the scoping rules in CF9 the `var` keyword is not really needed. 
Variables can be added to the `LOCAL` scope directly and at any time (`<cfset LOCAL.foo = "bar"`). There is no need scope them ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I should start by pointing out that your code doesn't var scope the variables, it just sets their values.  You need to use the VAR keyword (or LOCAL scope in CF9) to specify that the variables should be VAR scoped.

Furthermore, chaining assignments doesn't work in all versions of CF.  My workplace is still on 6.1, and this throws an error.

Finally, if I recall correctly, if you use the assignment statement as above, var1 and var2 are equal to true, as the result of an assignment operation is true if no error occurred.  (someone correct me if I'm wrong, since I can't test it at work, since we're on 6.1)

Anyway, to get back to your question, I don't chain assignment or scoping ever.  First, I think individual assignments are clearer.  second, it doesn't work in all versions.  So I would suggest that individual assignments would be preferred.

Comment: I do not like chaining either, but a quick test with CF9 shows all variables equal to an empty string. However `var2` and `var3` are placed in the shared `variables` scope (not function local).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people simply create a var struct and define your variables as keys for the struct. This way you don't have to use var all the time. E.g.:

```
<cfset var local = structNew() />
<cfset local.var1 = "" />
<cfset local.var2 = "" />
```

This is helpful for those who use ColdFusion Server 8 and below and are stuck with the var scope.